# Sending a message to a specific client with Spring Websockets

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, websocket

So I've got a Runnable class that should invoke the method notifyUser(String username, String content) once a certain criteria is met. I've been trying to get this to work but it always fails with NullPointerExceptions. This has most likely to do with an Autowiring failure (since the Runnable class is not managed by Spring). Autowiring SimpMessagingTemplate in a Spring-managed context works just fine and the methods do what they're supposed to.

What I want to do is to invoke the method (or a similar method) convertAndSendToUser of the SimpMessagingTemplate, but I cannot autowire it in this context. Everything I've tried failed so far, which is why I assume I got some of the basic concepts wrong.

My Configuration looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/test");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/test").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

Update: I've managed to get rid of the NullPointerException by using the following code .. but messages (convertAndSendToUser() as well as convertAndSend()) don't get picked up by the client. The developer console doesn't show any incoming messages.

```
AbstractApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Application.class);
ctx.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(myService);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's true because you do this:

```
new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Application.class);
```

in that your class, meaning starting a new full `appicationContext`. But your `user` is registered in the another context.

It isn't clear why you can't make your component managed by Spring, but there is no other way to use `SimpMessagingTemplate`, if you can't reach `applicationContext`.

It would be better to share that your code to investigate from our side and decide how can we help there.

Maybe you can use there `WebApplicationContextUtils`...

Comment: Well I genereally probably should focus on making the thread spring-managed then instead of overcomplicating things with workarounds. Can you point me in the right direction on how to start a spring managed thread? As far as I can tell, I need to get the thread as a bean via context and start it with ThreadPoolTaskExecutor, but where and how do I define that Thread bean?

Comment: You should just make your `Runnable` managed by Spring and `@Autowire` there everything you'd like. This one can be `prototype` as well. The starter should be managed as well to have an ability to `ctx.getBean()` for your `Runnable`.